# python tkinter with a simple web wrapper

Tags: python, tkinter

I am writing a simple python program with a UI, and i can't find out how to put a web page inside the program. I tried searching on Google, but i can't find any simple implementations.
Any links would be great. Just to recap, i just want a simple GUI python program with a webpage embeded inside it, basically like this:

```
# File: hello1.py

from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

w = Label(root, text="This is where i was the web page embeded")
w.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks,

EDIT:

Solved the problem, used webkit

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import gtk
import webkit
import gobject

gobject.threads_init()
win = gtk.Window()
bro = webkit.WebView()
bro.open("http://www.google.com")
win.add(bro)
win.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Jack

Comment: I do not know how to do this with Tkinter. There is no Webbrowser widget. Maybe you can build one using `import webbrowser`. Let us know if you succeed!

Comment: More on this: http://www.aclevername.com/articles/python-webgui/

Answer (score 20):

You can both embed HTML and open full web-pages (with CSS and javascript even) in tkinter. With the [cefpython module](https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython) you can embed a full-blown Chromium browser in a tk window.

```
from cefpython3 import cefpython as cef
import ctypes
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk
import sys
import platform
import logging as _logging

# Fix for PyCharm hints warnings
WindowUtils = cef.WindowUtils()

# Platforms
WINDOWS = (platform.system() == "Windows")
LINUX = (platform.system() == "Linux")
MAC = (platform.system() == "Darwin")

# Globals
logger = _logging.getLogger("tkinter_.py")

class MainFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.browser_frame = None
        self.navigation_bar = None

        # Root
        root.geometry("900x640")
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)

        # MainFrame
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.master.title("Tkinter example")
        self.master.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)
        self.master.bind("<Configure>", self.on_root_configure)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)

        # NavigationBar
        self.navigation_bar = NavigationBar(self)
        self.navigation_bar.grid(row=0, column=0,
                                 sticky=(tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W))
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self, 0, weight=0)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, 0, weight=0)

        # BrowserFrame
        self.browser_frame = BrowserFrame(self, self.navigation_bar)
        self.browser_frame.grid(row=1, column=0,
                                sticky=(tk.N + tk.S + tk.E + tk.W))
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self, 1, weight=1)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, 0, weight=1)

        # Pack MainFrame
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=tk.YES)

    def on_root_configure(self, _):
        logger.debug("MainFrame.on_root_configure")
        if self.browser_frame:
            self.browser_frame.on_root_configure()

    def on_configure(self, event):
        logger.debug("MainFrame.on_configure")
        if self.browser_frame:
            width = event.width
            height = event.height
            if self.navigation_bar:
                height = height - self.navigation_bar.winfo_height()
            self.browser_frame.on_mainframe_configure(width, height)

    def on_focus_in(self, _):
        logger.debug("MainFrame.on_focus_in")

    def on_focus_out(self, _):
        logger.debug("MainFrame.on_focus_out")

    def on_close(self):
        if self.browser_frame:
            self.browser_frame.on_root_close()
        self.master.destroy()

    def get_browser(self):
        if self.browser_frame:
            return self.browser_frame.browser
        return None

    def get_browser_frame(self):
        if self.browser_frame:
            return self.browser_frame
        return None

class BrowserFrame(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, navigation_bar=None):
        self.navigation_bar = navigation_bar
        self.closing = False
        self.browser = None
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.bind("<FocusIn>", self.on_focus_in)
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_focus_out)
        self.bind("<Configure>", self.on_configure)
        self.focus_set()

    def embed_browser(self):
        window_info = cef.WindowInfo()
        rect = [0, 0, self.winfo_width(), self.winfo_height()]
        window_info.SetAsChild(self.get_window_handle(), rect)
        self.browser = cef.CreateBrowserSync(window_info,
                                             url="http://www.google.com") #todo
        assert self.browser
        self.browser.SetClientHandler(LoadHandler(self))
        self.browser.SetClientHandler(FocusHandler(self))
        self.message_loop_work()

    def get_window_handle(self):
        if self.winfo_id() > 0:
            return self.winfo_id()
        elif MAC:
            from AppKit import NSApp
            import objc
            return objc.pyobjc_id(NSApp.windows()[-1].contentView())
        else:
            raise Exception("Couldn't obtain window handle")

    def message_loop_work(self):
        cef.MessageLoopWork()
        self.after(10, self.message_loop_work)

    def on_configure(self, _):
        if not self.browser:
            self.embed_browser()

    def on_root_configure(self):
        # Root <Configure> event will be called when top window is moved
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()

    def on_mainframe_configure(self, width, height):
        if self.browser:
            if WINDOWS:
                ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(
                    self.browser.GetWindowHandle(), 0,
                    0, 0, width, height, 0x0002)
            elif LINUX:
                self.browser.SetBounds(0, 0, width, height)
            self.browser.NotifyMoveOrResizeStarted()

    def on_focus_in(self, _):
        logger.debug("BrowserFrame.on_focus_in")
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.SetFocus(True)

    def on_focus_out(self, _):
        logger.debug("BrowserFrame.on_focus_out")
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.SetFocus(False)

    def on_root_close(self):
        if self.browser:
            self.browser.CloseBrowser(True)
            self.clear_browser_references()
        self.destroy()

    def clear_browser_references(self):
        self.browser = None

class LoadHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, browser_frame):
        self.browser_frame = browser_frame

    def OnLoadStart(self, browser, **_):
        if self.browser_frame.master.navigation_bar:
            self.browser_frame.master.navigation_bar.set_url(browser.GetUrl())

class FocusHandler(object):

    def __init__(self, browser_frame):
        self.browser_frame = browser_frame

    def OnTakeFocus(self, next_component, **_):
        logger.debug("FocusHandler.OnTakeFocus, next={next}"
                     .format(next=next_component))

    def OnSetFocus(self, source, **_):
        logger.debug("FocusHandler.OnSetFocus, source={source}"
                     .format(source=source))
        return False

    def OnGotFocus(self, **_):
        """Fix CEF focus issues (#255). Call browser frame's focus_set
           to get rid of type cursor in url entry widget."""
        logger.debug("FocusHandler.OnGotFocus")
        self.browser_frame.focus_set()

class NavigationBar(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.back_state = tk.NONE
        self.forward_state = tk.NONE
        self.back_image = None
        self.forward_image = None
        self.reload_image = None
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)

        # Back button
        back = b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgBAMAAAAQtmoLAAAAKlBMVEUAAAAyMjIzMzMzMzMyMjIzMzMxMTEzMzMtLS0zMzMkJCQyMjIrKysxMTExeYOJAAAADnRSTlMAgH3/cGlU1BHPDsoMWDQYbKYAAACNSURBVHgB7deBBYBAAIXha4YWaIdXJYlGaJwAzRFojhMarQnO+eWg3g9AvijnXXDZnKuawKpbCEgLA6QOAtLKAKmHgDYIDLuBDDBS4KDA+TsgQmC6IXAZyADpEkA6CogC/AH+SpQIlIAf7v2vYSIGfJBR4ihFmNjx+KHE8AliLjlD6dAFUxqMdX4dcM49/KeCIizV7gUAAAAASUVORK5CYII='        
        self.back_image = tk.PhotoImage(data=back)
        self.back_image = self.back_image.zoom(25).subsample(100)
        self.back_button = tk.Button(self, image=self.back_image,command=self.go_back)
        self.back_button.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # Forward button
        forward = b'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGAAAABgCAYAAADimHc4AAAA1UlEQVR4Ae3cAQbCYBzG4Q6QiI4wYIbtPU1HCAgQSOcLgtBtamHQAb5/43noAu8Pmu37NgAAAAAAAAAAAC0luU7TdNuUMP4lyfv7E6GxefDzMr4IheOL0FiS0zK2CI2N43hcRhahQJJDkqcIhYZh2IsgAiKIgAgi8BPhURiBrut2IoiACCIgggj8WQQR5mHvhRHo+35bEAERBMD4xl8V4/v7iQcw42N842N8L+XxWYrxMb7xMb5TMsZ/GX+Nh/RwTNVBbVxV4LIOXFcDAAAAAAAAAADwAephJFWvaMW3AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC'        
        self.forward_image = tk.PhotoImage(data=forward)
        self.forward_image = self.forward_image.zoom(25).subsample(100)
        self.forward_button = tk.Button(self, image=self.forward_image,command=self.go_forward)
        self.forward_button.grid(row=0, column=1)

#        Reload button
        refresh = b'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'        
        self.reload_image = tk.PhotoImage(data=refresh)
        self.reload_image = self.reload_image.zoom(25).subsample(100)
        self.reload_button = tk.Button(self, image=self.reload_image,command=self.reload)
        self.reload_button.grid(row=0, column=2)

        # Url entry
        self.url_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        tk.Grid.rowconfigure(self, 0, weight=100)
        tk.Grid.columnconfigure(self, 3, weight=100)

        # Update state of buttons
        self.update_state()

    def go_back(self):
        if self.master.get_browser():
            self.master.get_browser().GoBack()

    def go_forward(self):
        if self.master.get_browser():
            self.master.get_browser().GoForward()

    def reload(self):
        if self.master.get_browser():
            self.master.get_browser().Reload()

    def set_url(self, url):
        self.url_entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        self.url_entry.insert(0, url)

    def on_url_focus_in(self, _):
        logger.debug("NavigationBar.on_url_focus_in")

    def on_url_focus_out(self, _):
        logger.debug("NavigationBar.on_url_focus_out")

    def on_load_url(self, _):
        if self.master.get_browser():
            self.master.get_browser().StopLoad()
            self.master.get_browser().LoadUrl(self.url_entry.get())

    def on_button1(self, _):
        """Fix CEF focus issues (#255). See also FocusHandler.OnGotFocus."""
        logger.debug("NavigationBar.on_button1")
        self.master.master.focus_force()

    def update_state(self):
        browser = self.master.get_browser()
        if not browser:
            if self.back_state != tk.DISABLED:
                self.back_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.back_state = tk.DISABLED
            if self.forward_state != tk.DISABLED:
                self.forward_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.forward_state = tk.DISABLED
            self.after(100, self.update_state)
            return
        if browser.CanGoBack():
            if self.back_state != tk.NORMAL:
                self.back_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.back_state = tk.NORMAL
        else:
            if self.back_state != tk.DISABLED:
                self.back_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.back_state = tk.DISABLED
        if browser.CanGoForward():
            if self.forward_state != tk.NORMAL:
                self.forward_button.config(state=tk.NORMAL)
                self.forward_state = tk.NORMAL
        else:
            if self.forward_state != tk.DISABLED:
                self.forward_button.config(state=tk.DISABLED)
                self.forward_state = tk.DISABLED
        self.after(100, self.update_state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    logger.setLevel(_logging.INFO)
    stream_handler = _logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = _logging.Formatter("[%(filename)s] %(message)s")
    stream_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
    logger.info("CEF Python {ver}".format(ver=cef.__version__))
    logger.info("Python {ver} {arch}".format(
            ver=platform.python_version(), arch=platform.architecture()[0]))
    logger.info("Tk {ver}".format(ver=tk.Tcl().eval('info patchlevel')))
    assert cef.__version__ >= "55.3", "CEF Python v55.3+ required to run this"
    sys.excepthook = cef.ExceptHook  # To shutdown all CEF processes on error
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainFrame(root)
    # Tk must be initialized before CEF otherwise fatal error (Issue #306)
    cef.Initialize()
    app.mainloop()
    cef.Shutdown()
```

Comment: @thescribe-ReinstateMonica what's the error message?

Comment: Exception: Python version not supported: 3.8.0

Comment: @thescribe-ReinstateMonica fix seems scheduled for next release https://github.com/cztomczak/cefpython/issues/546

Comment: @delica getting error: Python version not supported: 3.8.2

Comment: Those python versions are not supported, on fedora I just ran `sudo dnf install python3.6` now it works. you have to run python3.6 your_browser.py to make it run with this version of python. (you could use pyenv though)

Answer (score 7):

Try using Tkinterweb!
https://pypi.org/project/tkinterweb/

Demo code:

```
from tkinterweb import HtmlFrame #import the HTML browser
try:
  import tkinter as tk #python3
except ImportError:
  import Tkinter as tk #python2

root = tk.Tk() #create the tkinter window
frame = HtmlFrame(root) #create HTML browser

frame.load_website("http://google.com") #load a website
frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True) #attach the HtmlFrame widget to the parent window
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using pywebview ?
It doesn't run in tkinter. but it is simple.

https://pypi.org/project/pywebview/

```
import webview
webview.create_window('Hello world', 'https://pywebview.flowrl.com/hello')
webview.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

class TesButaWarna:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.title("Tes Buta Warna")
        self.root.geometry("400x200")

        self.current_plate = 0
        self.plates = [
            {"image_path": "plate_1.png", "answer": 12},
            {"image_path": "plate_2.png", "answer": 8},
            {"image_path": "plate_3.png", "answer": 29}
            # Tambahkan plate lainnya di sini
        ]

        self.label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Apakah Anda bisa melihat angka di bawah ini?")
        self.label.pack(pady=10)

        self.image_label = tk.Label(self.root)
        self.image_label.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry.pack(pady=10)

        self.button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Submit", command=self.check_answer)
        self.button.pack()

        self.show_next_plate()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def show_next_plate(self):
        if self.current_plate < len(self.plates):
            plate = self.plates[self.current_plate]
            image_path = plate["image_path"]
            self.answer = plate["answer"]

            image = tk.PhotoImage(file=image_path)
            self.image_label.configure(image=image)
            self.image_label.image = image

            self.entry.delete(0, tk.END)
            self.current_plate += 1
        else:
            self.root.destroy()

    def check_answer(self):
        user_answer = self.entry.get()
        if user_answer == str(self.answer):
            messagebox.showinfo("Hasil", "Jawaban BENAR! Anda tidak buta warna.")
        else:
            messagebox.showinfo("Hasil", "Jawaban SALAH! Anda mungkin mengalami buta warna.")

        self.show_next_plate()
```

## Start program

```
TesButaWarna()
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: Also, answers should be in English. I've translated "memulai" to "start", but it'd be useful to translate the strings within the code to English, so your answer is clear for contributors who don't speak Bahasa Indonesia.

Answer (score -6):

the simple answer will be is stop wasting your time please learn electron js for making apps b/c after this when you try to compile your tkinter project will be so ugly so learn js then electron my suggestion

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32647950)