# How to display rendered html content in text widget of tkinter in python 3.4.x

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I want to display my mails as it is in text widget of tkinter in python 3.4.
It can be printed as HTML formatted way by using `message.HTMLBody`. How do I render it in my text widget and display the content

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python tkinter with a simple web wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706069/python-tkinter-with-a-simple-web-wrapper)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've managed to render simple html tags using [tkhtml](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml).

Install using `pip3 install tkinterhtml`, then, using the [package example](https://bitbucket.org/aivarannamaa/tkinterhtml/src/master/tkinterhtml/__main__.py?fileviewer=file-view-default):

```
from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame

frame = HtmlFrame(root, horizontal_scrollbar="auto")
 
frame.set_content("<html></html>")
```

If you want to directly render a webpage, you can do this to request and render it:

```
import urllib
frame.set_content(urllib.request.urlopen("https://duckduckgo.com").read().decode())
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 4):

Short of anything past very basic HTML tkinter just wasn't built for this. There's [tkhtml](http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/) as one option, but anything past basic html you'll want to look elsewhere. Tk can do a lot of amazing things, but embedding webpages / content isn't really one of them.

If you just want the text / some basic images / formatting from your mail, then you can scrape the data and then render and format it through the standard tk widgets.

I don't really like recommending other packages / options as it tends to be highly opinionated, but check out PyQt. Specifically, the QtWebkit.

Comment: can you help me out with an example code of tkhtml?  Thanks

Comment: It sounds like tkinter would be capable of rendering Wiki page html, something on par with Wikipedia pages.  Do you know about html forms?

Comment: If you mean display forms as in html forms then in a form yes... I've built plenty of GUI's that parse the html for forms and dynamically recreates them through tk widgets etc and then sends the data off for web scraping purposes

Comment: So javascript inside the html wouldnt be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

The package [tkhtmlview](https://pypi.org/project/tkhtmlview/) is a collection of tkinter widgets whose text can be set in HTML format, that is just what I needed.

### Example

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkhtmlview import HTMLLabel

root = tk.Tk()
html_label = HTMLLabel(root, html='<h1 style="color: red; text-align: center"> Hello World </H1>')
html_label.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
html_label.fit_height()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: any idea how to retrieve HTML from HTMLText if I made edits to the text when I run the script?