# Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005) in Tkinter HtmlFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I am trying render html tags in tkinter but I always get this error:

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

I tried everything But I failed everytime

Can someone help to me?

here is my code:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk

from tkinterhtml import HtmlFrame

root = tk.Tk()

frame = HtmlFrame(root, horizontal_scrollbar="auto")
frame.grid(sticky=tk.NSEW)

frame.set_content("""
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hello world!</h1>
</body>
</html>    
""")


root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Try this should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084313/how-to-display-rendered-html-content-in-text-widget-of-tkinter-in-python-3-4-x

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the python interpreter: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance/application-error-0xc0000005/6224ae45-a251-4f21-b076-74524618d00a

Comment: I tried this ways but It still give same error. Thank you ur commends