# Why pygment Syntax Highlighting not highlighting my code?

Tags: python, tkinter, text, pygments

I am making a text editor in python with a **Syntax Highlighting** feature.

I used `pygment` module, but it is not highlighting my code rather printing plain `html` code.

This is my code :

```
from tkinter import*
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import PythonLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter

root=Tk()
code="hello "
formatter = HtmlFormatter()
css = formatter.get_style_defs()
div = highlight(code, PythonLexer(), formatter)
text=Text()
text.insert(INSERT,div)
text.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I want that the highlighted code should be inserted in my `Text widget` but plain HTML code is inserted.

Thanks :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084313/how-to-display-rendered-html-content-in-text-widget-of-tkinter-in-python-3-4-x

Comment: go through my question carefully  I just want code highlighting!

Comment: HTML is HTML.  The standard text widget doesn't support its display.  If you want HTML support, then you need to use a widget that does support it.

Comment: can you name such widget?

Comment: Look at the link I referenced.  tkhtml (http://tkhtml.tcl.tk/index.html) is a Tk widget that supports basic html display.  The python tkinterhtml module is a wrapper for tkhtml.  Take a closer look at the link I referenced.

Comment: It's ok but can you detect     pygment not highlighting my code?

Comment: tkinter Text widget does not handle HTML tags.  Try [tk-html-widgets](https://pypi.org/project/tk-html-widgets/)