# how to make a website viewer python that views a website

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, python-2.7

I wanted to make a program that will view this website in a window with sound not opening any sort of browser but I can not seem to find any thing what would help me

Comment: You seem to be drawing a distinction between "viewing" a website and opening a browser. If you have a program that can view a website, that program *is* a browser, for all intents and purposes. As such, it's really unclear what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: You would basically have to write your own HTML rendering software from the ground up. This is very difficult, which is why we usually let existing browsers do it.

Comment: i needed it to view a website as a browswer

Comment: @DerekLeyman: That doesn't make things any clearer. I think you probably have an X-Y problem here. Rather than asking about *how to implement a solution to your problem*, you should instead *describe the problem you're trying to solve* -- that way you will get useful answers. As it stands, this question is too unclear to even be answerable.

Comment: i needed it to view a website as a browser in a window created by by python not by any of the installed browsers on my computer @DanielPryden

Comment: @DerekLeyman: Are you asking about *embedding* a web view into your Python application? That is going to be... difficult, but at least plausible. Can you [edit] your question to clarify that?

Comment: @DerekLeyman: As rephrased, it looks like the following questions might already have an answer for you: [python tkinter with a simple web wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706069/python-tkinter-with-a-simple-web-wrapper) and/or [How to display rendered html content in text widget of tkinter in python 3.4.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37084313/how-to-display-rendered-html-content-in-text-widget-of-tkinter-in-python-3-4-x).

Comment: I would like web view or something @DanielPryden

Comment: @DerekLeyman: Don't keep adding comments to clarify: you need to [edit] your question to add all the relevant information. Importantly, you need to describe *which UI toolkit* you're using. Is it `tkinter`? (If so, you're probably out of luck.) Describe how you're creating the window that you want to put the web content into. I don't know the answer myself but if you clarify your question then someone else should be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

PyQt Designer should be able to do this. You can tell it what website you want it to go to, and then just either make the window transparent, or make it hidden. The Widget you would use for this is QWebEngineViewer.