# How to embed an external webpage in tkinter without using cefpython3

Tags: python, html, windows, tkinter

I want to embed a webpage like google.com in my Tkinter program and take actions on that webpage from the program itself.
I have read the solution to a similar problem here- [python tkinter with a simple web wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706069/python-tkinter-with-a-simple-web-wrapper) but since I don't want to embed the whole browser it wasn't helpful

PS: Using Python 3.9

Comment: Instead of tkinter you can try on PyQt/PySide, tkinter is a very basic gui compare to these..

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python 3.7 or earlier, this can be easily done using the cefpython3 module (pip install cefpython3). **If you have Python 3.8 or 3.9, consider downgrading, to make it work.** In other words, install Python 3.6 (just to be safe).

Refer to this answer for the code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55511751/15835249

I hope this helps you! Happy coding!

Comment: The link in OP question already suggests using `cefpython3` and OP has said *"don't want to embed the whole browser"*.