# Displaying HTML pd DataFrames in Tkinter window

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, tkinter

I would like to display a dataframe as HTML table in tkinter window. I have seen options where I put the dataframe in treeview or use pandastable. However, what I am looking for is to display the table in the tkinter window exactly like it is displayed when I call the table() function. It is more of a visualization thing. Tree view is not good for visualization and pandastable is too complex for my purpose. Is there a way to display the dataframe in the tkinter window exactly like it is displayed in the terminal when I run the code outside of the tkinter window?? I would appreciate the help.

```
from tkinter import *
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from IPython.display import display, clear_output, HTML
def table():
   df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
   display(HTML(df.to_html()))

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=400, width=500)


termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)    

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: tkinter itself has no ability to render html. You'll need to use a third party library.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! any suggestion of the third party libraries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python tkinter with a simple web wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14706069/python-tkinter-with-a-simple-web-wrapper)

Comment: I am trying to embed a local HTML file not a website. From what I can see that this is from websites

Comment: Why not create a local file ```temp.html``` and navigate to ```file:///temp.html```? Also most webview libraries support to execute a javascript and you can set the HTML content using the ```document.write()```.